# PHP namespace/class not found with composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I created my first PHP library to host on GitHub.

https://github.com/TBETool/password-generator

on installing the library in my PHP Application using composer, the directory structure is like
vendor

```
|- tbetool
   |- php-password-generator
      |- src
         |- PasswordGenerator.php
      |- README.md
      |- composer.json
```

Content of `composer.json` is

```
{
    "name": "tbetool/php-password-generator",
    "type": "library",
    "homepage": "http://thebornengineer.com",
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0"
    }
}
```

content of **PasswordGenerator.php**

```
<?php
namespace TBETool;

/**
 * Class PasswordGenerator
 * @package TBETool
 */
class PasswordGenerator
{
   // content goes here
}
```

and entry in my project's composer.json at `/composer.json`

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6",
    .... other packages....
    "tbetool/php-password-generator": "^1.2"
},
```

But when I use in my program.

```
<?php

use TBETool\PasswordGenerator;
class MyClass {
   function myFun() {
       $password = new PasswordGenerator();
   }
}
```

But it gives error as

**Class 'TBETool\PasswordGenerator' not found**

**Is there something error with setting up my library to be used using composer?**

Comment: I've never written a library but I presume you need an `autoload` section somewhere in your `composer.json` file. How do you load classes when using it locally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a psr-4 autoloading in your composer.json file

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Namespace\\": "root/path/for/namespace"
    }
}
```

then dump your autoload `composer dump-autoload`